# No Orders in Reports > Sales - Orders

Tags: magento2, reports, lifetime-sales

I can't find any record in Reports Orders (reports/report_sales/sales/) even if I tried to place some order from the store.

Answer (score 4):

You need to refresh the `Refresh Statistics` in **report** -> **Statistics** -> **Refresh Statistics**.

Orders whose status is `completed` will only be shown in reports.

Select All reports checkbox and refresh lifetime Statistics.

[image]

Comment: done, but still empty and the sales/order/ page contains all the orders, but in reports  I see nothing

Comment: Only completed order status will be comes in order report.

Answer (score 1):

You first have to generate the statistics.

Orders with the status `new` or `pending` will not appear in that grid

Answer (score 1):

I have M2.3.3 and sales report allows to filter by specific order status, but "new", "pending" and "pending payment" cannot be selected.

IMHO it does not make sense not to also show these options.